# How can I post data using AJAX to update my MVC View

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

Hello everyone I'm currently working on a ASP.NET MVC environment using C#, so right now I'm getting a table from a URL using AJAX and using C# to render it inside my cshtml.

Anyways right now I have a problem where I don't find a way to post data from a button since I'm using javascript mostly to do this I'm kind of lost.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
        $("#mydataTable").on('click','.btnSelect',function(){
             // get the current row
             var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");

             // get current row 1st table cell TD value
             var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(9)").html(); 

             var data=col1;

             alert(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Right now this is the script I'm using to get data from the row I want to get data from.

How can I submit this variable at the same time using AJAX to my Controller

I currently use this other script to send data to my controller but it takes the values out of `<input> name=""`, the value I need to get is from a table I render using c# in my cshtml

```
<script>
    function load() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@myproject.Models.Base.RootDir()Controller/View',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'text',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            data: $("#myForms").serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                $('#divToDisplayData').html(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

If anyone has a question please ask, I'll be around all day

And this is the button I use to submit data

```
 <button class="btnSelect">Seleccionar</button>
```

Comment: What you want to post?, What issue you are facing?. Please describe more clearly. As i can see currently you are posting whole form.

Comment: How can I add data gotten from first script var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(9)").html(); that triggers on a button call and at the same time bound that to a submit post with my ajax call data: , how do i do that

Comment: Ok so when your ajax call is executing, you want to pass your cell value with your `form`, right?

Comment: yes sir actually yes

Comment: call ajax after  var data=col1 ?

Comment: yea and use var data in ajax how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Pass data inside your form, you just need to take one hidden field inside your form, so when you button clicked, set the value of that hidden field.

```
<form id="myForms">

     //your controlls

     //one extra hidden field
     <input type="hidden" id="cellValue" />

</form>
```

Now on button click, set the value of above hidden field.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // code to read selected table row cell data (values).
        $("#mydataTable").on('click','.btnSelect',function(){
             // get the current row
             var currentRow=$(this).closest("tr");

             // get current row 1st table cell TD value
             var col1=currentRow.find("td:eq(9)").html(); 

             var data=col1;

             $('#cellValue').val(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

so finally, when your `load()` method call, in the `$("#myForms").serialize()` you will get your cell value in the hidden field control.

Here, you need to take care that whenever you pass html from view to controller, controller will deny your request because it is not safe content. so you need to use `[ValidateInput(false)]` on your action as below.

```
public class YourController: Controller{

        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult View()
        {
             return View();
        }
 }
```

Comment: THanks for sharing your knowledge Vishal :D appreciate it a lot